# Upload customer GPS location to db

Tags: django, geolocation

I'm trying to to upload customer GPS location to db. I got the following error message when running the server.

My code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geo_models
class Order(models.Model):
table_num = models.ForeignKey(Table,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
value=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,default=0)
state=models.IntegerField(default=0)
lan= models.IntegerField(default=0)
location = geo_models.PointField()

def __str__(self):
   return str(self.id)
```

The error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL 
library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0", "gdal1.11.0", " 
gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting 
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

Comment: Did you install  GDAL library?

Comment: Thank you for answer , I have installed GDAL and this problem has solved, put when make migrate to Order model appears the following message:   AttributeErrore : 'Database operations ' has no attribute' adabter '

Comment: What's your database?